# how to reference an already filtered table in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm filtering an html table using jquery, I have a filter for every column and it works just fine, but right now if I filter the second column after filtering the first one (example), it refilters the entire table and I want it to filter the already filtered table.

Here is the table.

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr>
                    <td class='table-row'>" . $row["conditions"] . "</td>
                    <td class='table-row'>" . $row["modelYears"] . "</td>
                    <td class='table-row'>" . $row["makes"] . "</td>
                    <td class='table-row'>" . $row["models"] . "</td>
                    <td class='table-row'>" . $row["contactNumbers"] . "</td>
                    <td class='table-row'>" . $row["supplierName"] . "</td>
                    <td class='table-row'>" . $row["supplierAddress"] . "</td>
                    <td class='table-row'>" . $row["supplierFullAddress"] . "</td>
                    <td class='table-row'>" . $row["supplierComment"] . "</td>
                </tr>";
        }
```

Here are 3 examples of the input fields in thead.

```
 <th><input id="con" type="text" placeholder="condition"></th>
 <th><input id="cyears" type="text" placeholder="modelyears"></th>
 <th><input id="cmakes" type="text" placeholder="makes"></th>
```

Here are two examples of the script I'm using to filter each column.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#con").on("keyup", function() {
                    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                    $("#geeks tr").filter(function() {
                        $(this).toggle($(this.children[0]).text()
                        .toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
                    });
                });
            });
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#cyears").on("keyup", function() {
                    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                    $("#geeks tr").filter(function() {
                        $(this).toggle($(this.children[1]).text()
                        .toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
                    });
                });
            });
```

is there a way I can reference the already filtered table?

Comment: I would maintain some kind of state variable of which filters are selected. When that variable changes, update your UI in one single filtering function based on the current filters :)

Comment: Similar to above, create an `applyFilter()` function and the first thing it does is reset the filter then build it again from the filter UI.  This way you can also apply it on page load if needed.